# How to override method from extend activity?

Tags: java, android, inheritance, android-activity

I have 2 activity. One is `AlertDialogActivity` & second is `MainActivity`. I extend `AlertDialogActivity` in `MainActivity`.

like this `public class MainActivity extends AlertDialogActivity`

now how to override method which is in `AlertDialogActivity` to my `MainActivity`?

AlertDialogActivity:

```
package com.jimmytrivedi.alertdialog;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class AlertDialogActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_alert_dialog);
        showAlertDialog(AlertDialogActivity.this);
    }

    private void showAlertDialog(final Context context) {
        // 1. Instantiate an <code><a href="/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html">AlertDialog.Builder</a></code> with its constructor
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(AlertDialogActivity.this);

// 2. Chain together various setter methods to set the dialog characteristics
        builder.setMessage("How are you?")
                .setTitle("Hello");

// 3. Get the <code><a href="/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html">AlertDialog</a></code> from <code><a href="/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#create()">create()</a></code>
        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();


    }

}
```

Comment: You override just like you would override any method from a parent class. What is the problem here?

Comment: @SushobhNadiger when I type showAlertDialog, it is not showing in suggestion.

Comment: @서강원 No, not working

Comment: @PoojaSingh ya you should change visibility of method show..., No Private

Comment: @서강원 yes, working. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the `showAlertDialog` `protected` instead of `private` , or even public if you want other classes to be able to call it.

```
protected void showAlertDialog(final Context context) {

}
```

Private methods can not be overriden.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to override a method Use  **abstract**  keyword

```
public abstract class AlertDialogActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_alert_dialog);
    showAlertDialog(AlertDialogActivity.this);
}

  public abstract void showAlertDialog(final Context context) {

    // 1. Instantiate an <code><a href="/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html">AlertDialog.Builder</a></code> with its constructor
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(AlertDialogActivity.this);

  // 2. Chain together various setter methods to set the dialog characteristics
    builder.setMessage("How are you?")
            .setTitle("Hello");

   // 3. Get the <code><a 
  href="/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html">AlertDialog</a></code> from <code><a 
  href="/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#create()">create()</a></code>
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Method should be with the same name and type.
Method should also **not be private**.

It can be **protected, package-private or public**. 
More about that you can find here:
[What is the difference between public, protected, package-private and private in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215497/what-is-the-difference-between-public-protected-package-private-and-private-in)